# instanciate list of my class name defined in a string

Tags: c#, string, list

What I'm trying is to instanciate a list with a class defined previously in a string variable. I don't even know if it is possible but I think so.

```
string class1 = "class1";
string class2 = "class2";
bool condition = getCondition();

string classToInstanciate = "";
if(condition) classToInstanciate = class1;
else classToInstanciate = class2;
```

`List<classToInstanciate> dtos = Parse(source).ToList();`

Here is the pb, obviously this won't work but I want to instanciate this list with the class which needs to be used.`

Comment: "this won't work" Why not?

Comment: Can I rephrase? You have a type-name as a string (that can change depending on some condition), and you want to create a `List<T>` where `T` is the type as named in the `string` - is that right? Is there any common API between the different possible types? some common base-class / interface, perhaps? or completely separate?

Comment: Because this doesn't work with this syntax

Comment: Marc, yes, this is what I want to achieve. There isn't common API, base class or interface. I need to instanciate list of custom objects.

Comment: Well, you can´t really **cast** - which is a compile-time-thing -  to a type provided at **runtime** - this is when you execute your code. That´s why Marc asked for a common base-type which you could use as `List<BaseClass>` instead. As this seems to be impossible for you all you **ever** get would be an `List<object>` or `List<dynamic>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic type arguments of a type in C# cannot be expressed loosely - they need to be quite explicit, so when you want to mix generics and reflection it always gets a bit messy.

The first job here is to get hold of a `Type` rather than a `string`. If you could use `typeof` throughout, it would be a lot simpler, i.e.

```
Type classToInstanciate;
if (condition) classToInstanciate = typeof(Class1);
else classToInstanciate = typeof(Class2);
```

Otherwise you're going to have to use `Type.GetType(fullyQualifiedName)` or `someAssembly.GetType(fullName)` etc, which gets messy.

Next, you need to switch from reflection (`Type`) to generics (`<T>`). There are multiple ways to do this, but the simplest is usually: `MakeGenericMethod`. For example:

```cs
class SomeType {
    // can make this non-public, but then you need to specify BindingFlags
    // in the GetMethod call
    public static List<T> DoTheThing<T>(whateverArgs) {
        List<T> dtos = Parse<T>(source).ToList(); // whatever...
        ///
        return dtos;
    }
    ...
    private static IList CallTheThing(Type type, whateverArgs)
    {
        return (IList) typeof(SomeType).GetMethod(nameof(DoTheThing))
              .MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, whateverArgs);
        // "null" above is the target instance; in this case static, hence null
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then you can use:

```cs
IList list = CallTheThing(classToInstanciate, otherArgs);
```

The `list` at the call-site is (and must be) only known as the non-generic `IList` API. If you need to use the generic aspects (`List<T>` etc) - you can do that inside `DoTheThing<T>`. The *list itself* is still a `List<T>` (of the correct `T`) even when only known as `IList` - so you can't add incorrect items to it etc.

Comment: "Then you can use:..." which won´t give you stronng types, which simply is impossible.

Comment: @HimBromBeere see the last line - they're "strong" inside `DoTheThing<T>`